# How to remove wrapper of certain selector with jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

While using animation on [`show()`](http://jqueryui.com/show/) with jQuery UI, `.ui-effects-wrapper` class has been added. How to remove the `.ui-effects-wrapper` class?

```js
$('.desc').eq(0).show();
$('.tab-child').hover(function(){
  $('.desc').hide();
  $('.desc').eq($(this).index()).show("shake", 4000);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.0/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
<div class="tab">
    <div class="tab-child">One</div>
    <div class="tab-child">Two</div>
    <div class="tab-child">Three</div>
    <div class="tab-child">Four</div>
</div>
<div class="content">
    <div class="desc" style="display: none;"> ONE: Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Ut ornare neque at velit fermentum, vulputate tempus
        lorem vulputate. Quisque eu ipsum venenatis, posuere tortor ut, maximus neque. Aenean tempor justo leo. Vestibulum
        auctor, urna ut scelerisque rutrum, sem arcu egestas ipsum, ut maximus magna turpis ut nunc. Nulla rutrum velit
        nisi, ac feugiat est commodo eu. Maecenas eget velit urna. Mauris posuere ex quis dictum commodo. Donec porta
        lobortis turpis, eget iaculis diam tincidunt at.
    </div>
    <div class="desc" style="display: none;"> TWO: Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Ut ornare neque at velit fermentum, vulputate tempus
        lorem vulputate. Quisque eu ipsum venenatis, posuere tortor ut, maximus neque. Aenean tempor justo leo. Vestibulum
        auctor, urna ut scelerisque rutrum, sem arcu egestas ipsum, ut maximus magna turpis ut nunc. Nulla rutrum velit
        nisi, ac feugiat est commodo eu. Maecenas eget velit urna. Mauris posuere ex quis dictum commodo. Donec porta
        lobortis turpis, eget iaculis diam tincidunt at.
    </div>
    <div class="desc" style="display: none;"> TREE: Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Ut ornare neque at velit fermentum, vulputate tempus
        lorem vulputate. Quisque eu ipsum venenatis, posuere tortor ut, maximus neque. Aenean tempor justo leo. Vestibulum
        auctor, urna ut scelerisque rutrum, sem arcu egestas ipsum, ut maximus magna turpis ut nunc. Nulla rutrum velit
        nisi, ac feugiat est commodo eu. Maecenas eget velit urna. Mauris posuere ex quis dictum commodo. Donec porta
        lobortis turpis, eget iaculis diam tincidunt at.
    </div>
    <div class="desc" style="display: none;"> FOUR: Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Ut ornare neque at velit fermentum, vulputate tempus
        lorem vulputate. Quisque eu ipsum venenatis, posuere tortor ut, maximus neque. Aenean tempor justo leo. Vestibulum
        auctor, urna ut scelerisque rutrum, sem arcu egestas ipsum, ut maximus magna turpis ut nunc. Nulla rutrum velit
        nisi, ac feugiat est commodo eu. Maecenas eget velit urna. Mauris posuere ex quis dictum commodo. Donec porta
        lobortis turpis, eget iaculis diam tincidunt at.
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: `.removeClass('.ui-effects-wrapper');`?

Comment: I think he was talking about the temporary div added by jQuery to produce the `shake` effect.

Comment: It is removed after the effect, right? Is it causing some sort of a problem?

Comment: @Zenoo exactly.

Comment: Why do you want to remove it? If you want the `shake` effect, you have to let jQuery do his thing.

Comment: I have to save DOM to database. So, I need to remove that wrapper before saving DOM if there is such wrapper. @Zenoo

Comment: Just wait for your animation to be done before saving anything.

Comment: @KiranShahi what you should do is get the child of 'ui-effects-wrapper' and call `$.replaceWith` to replace that div with its own child

Comment: try this, that shake is annoying and not sure why it's even there.
  `$('.desc').eq($(this).index()).show();`

Comment: You save the DOM to database? Good to know! So I could manipulate your DOM and you save it directly to the database? Nice! Can I get the URL please? ;) Okay, let's be honest: don't ever do that!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Find the children of that wrapper and remove the wrapper.

```
$(".ui-effects-wrapper").children().unwrap();
```

Answer (score 1):

In my comment I said "@KiranShahi what you should do is get the child of 'ui-effects-wrapper' and call $.replaceWith to replace that div with its own child"

I've implemented that here:

https://jsfiddle.net/Lopkcjnt/3/

```
$('.ui').each(function() {
  let children = $(this).children();
  $(this).replaceWith(children);
})
```

Then 'unwrap' method is perhaps even more intuitive though

https://api.jquery.com/unwrap/

Up to you.

Comment: unwrap will do what you told.

Answer (score 1):

If this is the element that you are wanting to remove the wapper class from $('.desc') add the following.

```
$('.desc').eq(0).show();

$('.tab-child').hover(function(){
  $('.desc').hide();
  $('.desc').eq($(this).index()).show("shake", 4000);
  $('.desc').removeClass('ui-effects-wrapper');
});
```

I ran your code above and I am not seeing that class added anywhere yet that which is added for the effect to run already goes away after the effect.

None the less, you can use that [`removeClass()`](https://api.jquery.com/removeclass/) on any element and for whatever class you are wanting to remove.